# How I can detect the background of an image programmatically?

Tags: image-processing, image-manipulation

I need to develop a software that selects a face from a photo where the background is a plain color (green, like in the movies).

Then we want to compose that selection with another background image, this part is easy with many libraries. But I don't know how can I do the selection? Can you give some links or libraries to investigate? I can do this project with any language of my choose, so examples or links in any language are welcome.

Comment: Conceptually this is actually very easy - just convert the green background pixels into a 0 alpha value, and draw the image onto the background image whereever you want.  In practice it can get a bit tricky around the edges of the border.  Can you describe a bit more about the technology you are using?  ie, is this windows, C++, etc.

Comment: GrandmasterB, thanks for your reply. I can use any language or plataform in windows, I was thinking use Java or C#. Can you share a link or example? I want to do some research but I can't find too much information in google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, what you are trying to do is called chroma key.  Like you say, it used a lot in the movies with a blue/green screen.  On windows its actually pretty easy to do because its built into windows as part of GDI+ (or on C#, I think its just called the Graphics class).

I dont have any sample code handy, but the process is pretty straight forward:

With GDI+, you create a bitmap object of your foreground image (the one with the green background).  Then create an ImageAttributes object.  Use ImageAttribute's object's SetColorKey() method to specify a color or range of colors to use as the background color.  Lastly, draw that bitmap object over the target bitmap, and GDI+ will draw it as if the background color is transparent.

There's more to it in that in code, but concept-wise thats all there is to it.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably an area where it is easier to work in some other space than RGB - such as HSV.

I would also look at the OpenCV library.